# Is there any evidence that this Yoda quote was inspired by Romans 5:3-4?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration

Yoda famously said that "Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering."

This seems to fit just a little too well with Romans 5:3-4, as rendered in some translations of the Bible:

> Not only this, but we also rejoice in our sufferings, knowing that suffering works perseverance, 
>   and perseverance, proven character; and proven character, hope.
>
> <sub>[World English Bible translation](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+5%3A3-4&version=WEB)</sub>

This could describe the sequel trilogy rather well. In particular, the reference to "hope" seems a little too close.

Lucas definitely borrowed heavily from other works. He also definitely lifted some things from the Bible, a fact acknowledged  by [current Lucasfilm employees](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-rebels-whats-in-a-name).  For example, the moon of [Endor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endor_(village)) is likely a Biblical name, one made famous by the Witch of Endor. And much more was borrowed in general themes, of course: Anakin's virgin birth, Luke and Anakin as saviors born in the desert.

Are  there any statements indicating that he may have been inspired by this passage?

Comment: Questions about the inspiration behind something are questions about science fiction and fantasy, you know. ;) We've had a *small* number of them.

Comment: It is, of course, impossible to prove a negative, but I can't recall reading anything about this, despite being quite into the mythology behind Star Wars, and I couldn't fin a source suggesting this connection after some searching. I'm leaning towards 'no'.

Comment: I always thought the hate-> suffering was borrowed from buddhisms dvesha -> dukkha

Comment: @Morrigan - a demonstration that that’s where it came from would be a good answer.

Comment: @Adamant noooo... unraveling authorial intent & inspiration is your forte,  not mine. Y'know i am too ignorant and lazy for it so i separate the work from the creator :P

Comment: The phrasing may be similar, but the messages of the two statements are quite different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Ignorance leads to fear, fear leads to hatred, and hatred leads to violence. This is the equation.

Quote by Ibn Rushd, famous Andalusian scholar,  that has most relevance here.

Comment: Indeed it would be very relevant! Can you find the original work in which this quote appears? I am having trouble.

Comment: Did some research, not 100 percent sure, but seems it's from one of his books. However could not find an English version. Averroes: Antologia

Comment: Can you find an Modern Arabic version online?

Comment: I'd also be interested in the original source or at least a date tied to this quote. I guess a reading of the Spanish anthology would give us a link back to the original source book. I'm not a Spanish reader though.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/In-which-work-if-any-did-Ibn-Rushd-Averroes-wrote-Ignorance-leads-to-fear-fear-leads-to-hate-and-hate-leads-to-violence-This-is-the-equation it would be worth adding a link to the book in question

Comment: Besides that goodreads assumption, there is no publication to be found which actually names a source for that quote.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no reasons to believe there is any connection here, for a couple of reasons.

This quote from Yoda was analyzed quite a bit, even before *The Phantom Menace* came out.  It was included as part of the teaser trailer.  All the pre-release footage of the film was gone over in excruciating detail by fans, and in all the online discussions about what we were learning about how the story of Episode I would take shape, there was never any suggestion that I came across that this was related Paul's Epistle to the Romans.

In terms of the content of the quotes, I also think there is actually very little similarity between the them.  They both contain elements superficially of the form *A leads to B; B leads to C; C leads to D*, but that is hardly an uncommon formula.  The specific linking phrases are used by Yoda are not shared by any of the major English translations.  (King James has very similar linkages to the World English Bible translation posted in the question, although the properties are rendered as "tribulation," "patience," "experience," and "hope.")

More significantly, I think, the quotes seem to be expressing completely opposite sentiments.  Paul is telling the early Christians to rejoice in their hardship, because it will help to lead them onto a true path of hopefulness.  Yoda is pointing out that negative emotions do not typically lead to positive ones.  Even a relatively unselfish negative emotion like fear can, if not addressed, lead to a cascade of other, even darker thoughts.  From the point of view of the Jedi, suffering is an end cause to be avoided, not (as Paul hoped) a beginning from which glorious ends may come.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly Buddhist. It's in a classic formula for describing causation. When discussing feeling and its associated mental phenomena, the Buddha talked about roots for particular mind states or qualities. There are unskillful roots (e.g. fear) and skillful roots (e.g. courage/striving). The three baseline unskillful roots are greed, anger, and delusion. These lead directly to suffering. The first lines of the Dhammapada (Treasury of Truth) demonstrates the logic of A leads to B - "Experiences are preceded by mind, led by mind, produced by mind. If one speaks or acts with an impure mind, suffering follows, even as the cart-wheel follows the hoof of the ox." Buddhist texts give long lists of unvirtous qualities and their negative effects. The distinction between skillful and unskillful thoughts and resulting behavior lies at the basis of everything the Buddha taught. In the Anguttara Nikaya (The Further-factored Discourses) the Buddha said that "a person, overpowered by negative, unwholesome states born of greed, being of uncontrolled mind, in this very life lives in pain, with distress and unrest." (Btw George Lucas said that he has been influenced by Buddhism and you can see this in many of the names in Star Wars e.g. Padme which is from the ubiquitous Tibetan mantra "Om mani padme hum." The Force is analogous to Sunyata (Emptiness or Great Oneness))

Comment: If you could [edit] in some sources for your claims (especially the bit about George Lucas saying he was influenced by Buddhism) it would help improve and solidify your answer

Answer (score -1):

The "fear leads to anger" quote appears to have been based on dialogue from *The Empire Strikes Back*. During the duel between Luke and Darth Vader:

> VADER: Impressive... most impressive.
>
> Luke jumps down to the platform where he is separated from Vader by the
> steaming carbonite pit.  He raises his hand.  His sword, which had
> fallen on another part of the platform, swiftly jumps into his
> outstretched hand and is instantly ignited.  Vader immediately lights
> his sword as well.
>
> VADER: Obi-Wan has taught you well.  **You have controlled your fear... now release your anger.**
>
> Luke is more cautious, controlling his anger.  He begins to retreat as
> Vader goads him on.  As Luke takes a defensive position, he realizes he
> has been foolhardy.  A quick sword exchange and Luke forces Vader back.
> Another exchange and Vader retreats.  Luke presses forward.
>
> VADER: **Only your hatred can destroy me.**
>
> <sub>(Source: https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html, emphasis added)</sub>

In this scene, Vader is actively trying to turn Luke to the dark side, so the intent for the Phantom Menace line seems to be to set up Vader as eventually inverting Yoda's teachings.